# Xamarin Firebase Cloud Messaging for iOS (appDelegate) RemoteMessageDelegate error

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to migrate the iOS handler for notifications to the firebase server. In the appDelegate.cs file, the documentation on the xamarin site (https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseioscloudmessaging) one of the steps are this:

```
// Register your app for remote notifications.
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (10, 0)) {
    // iOS 10 or later
    var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization (authOptions, (granted, error) => {
        Console.WriteLine (granted);
    });

    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

    // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
    Messaging.SharedInstance.RemoteMessageDelegate = this;
} else {
    // iOS 9 or before
    var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
    var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes (allNotificationTypes, null);
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings (settings);
}

UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications ();
```

Two lines of codes, the messaging.sharedinstance.... and UNUSerNotificationCenter.Current... receive the appdelegate workload. To make appdelegate implement the Usernotificationcenterdelegate, this works. However, this doesn't work for the Firebase message delegate.
The firebase message delegate doesn't get recognized. I have installed the cloud messaging package (v1.2.1.1), analytics (3.6.0), Core (3.4.5) and instance ID (1.0.8). These packages are installed through Nuget package manager.

Anyone with an idea why FIRMessagingDelegate can't be found, or is there something specific that needs to be done for the iOS packages of these versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FIRMessagingDelegate` is named `IMessagingDelegate`:

```
[Protocol (Name = "FIRMessagingDelegate", WrapperType = typeof(MessagingDelegateWrapper)), ProtocolMember (IsRequired = true, IsProperty = false, IsStatic = false, Name = "ApplicationReceivedRemoteMessage", Selector = "applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:", ParameterType = new Type[] {
 typeof(RemoteMessage) }, ParameterByRef = new bool[] { false }), Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 10, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
public interface IMessagingDelegate : INativeObject, IDisposable
{
  ~~~
```

Implement `IMessagingDelegate` on your `UIApplicationDelegate`:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
{
    ~~~~

    public void ApplicationReceivedRemoteMessage(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(remoteMessage);
    }

    ~~~~
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know! Thanks!
Apparently the "ApplicationReceivedRemoteMessage" function was already declared in the "getting started" documentation, but more disguised in the code further down. Should be rewritten, honestly, to address this issue!